# Ejecutar una macro desde un .bat

Tags: excel, batch, macros, excel-2013, excel-2010

Quería saber si es posible ejecutar una macro en Excel desde un archivo .bat

ya que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

La macro que poseo me funciona correctamente pero necesito que se ejecute cuando corra el .bat

Les agradecería si saben de algo, me puedan orientar.

gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que realizar los siguientes pasos:

1. En tu archivo .xlsm debes revisar tus macros y hacer doble click sobre el elemento **ThisWorkbook** y colocar el siguiente evento **Private Sub Workbook_Open()**

**Ejemplo:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Good Morning"
Call Macro1
End Sub
```

2. Crear un .bat que llame a tu archivo Excel:

   start Excel.exe Libro1.xlsm

Con eso debería de alcanzar.

Comentá como te fue.

Saludos!